# Convert CSV to nested JSON python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have input like below state is unique and district and villages can form a list from that list i have to form below JSON.

```
state,district,village
S1,D1,V1
S1,D1,V2
S1,D2,V1
S2,D1,V1
S2,D2,V2
```

```
{
  "staticvalue": {
    "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
    "staticvalue": "S1"
  },
  "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
  "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
  "staticvalue": {
    "staticValue": [
      {
        "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
        "staticvalue": "V1"
      },
      {
        "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
        "staticvalue": "V2"
      }
    ],
    "staticvalue": {
      "V1": [
        {
          "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
          "staticvalue": "D1"
        }
      ],
      "staticvalue": [
        {
          "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
          "staticvalue": "D1"
        },
        {
          "staticvalue": "staticvalue",
          "staticvalue": "D2"
        }
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

Adding some dummy text as stackoverflow detected that this post has less description.

Comment: What's the issue, reading the csv or creating the dict? For reading you have `csv.DictReader`, for creating the nested dict, iterate the items and have a dict where the state is the key, and the values are lista of options of district and village, it can be recursive to have a dict as value with disrict as key.

Comment: Here State and district have common values, we need to get uniq values for each state.